# Can you choose not to use Unity on install?

Tags: system-installation, gnome-classic

I have been using Ubuntu since version 9 and found it very friendly and wonderful to work with. Is there a way to choose Gnome-classic or other desktops on install or do I have to use Unity?

Answer (score 3):

Unity allows you to quickly access applications and files and to me, looks very good. Lack of productiveness is not a problem with the keyboard shortcuts it responds to. To display a list of shortcuts press and hold the Super key. The newly implemented HUD is also a goodie! Nevertheless, you can explore many other desktop environments. I also like Gnome Shell. It has a very clean look and is lightweight. Other options are Cinnamon, Enlightenment, etc. It's just a matter of what you feel most comfortable with!

Answer (score 3):

Unity supposedly has a lighter Display Manager than Gnome, and the design is supposed to be better in every scenario. Gnome tends to crowd in a netbook screen, in some cases. Unity is supposed to leave more visible real estate on the screen to work with. That's especially true if you enable the AUTO-HIDE for the panel as I do.

I also like LXDE (LUBUNTU) too. Very light, fast and familiar to those who are changing from an XP interface.